# How to set the bit in position?

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm

```
mov al, 100d ; 01100100
shr eax, 1 ; cf = 0
           ; 00110010
```

How to burn cf in 5th position?

For example:
My number 10000111. CF = 1 => 10001111

My main task is to make reverse byte using shr (shl). I want to do it myself, but I do not know how to set the bit in position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reversing the bits, just shift them in to the destination operand from the same end you shifted them out from the source (that is use opposite shifts). Sample code:

```
    mov al, 100  ; input = 01100100
    mov ah, 0    ; output
    mov ecx, 8   ; 8 bits to process
next:
    shr al, 1    ; shift next bit out to the right
    rcl ah, 1    ; shift it in from the right
    loop next
    ; result in ah = 38 = 0010 1100
```

Nevertheless, to answer your question: shift carry into a zeroed temporary register to the given position, then use bitwise `OR` to set it in the destination. Sample code:

```
mov dl, 0 ; zero temp register, without affecting CF
rcl dl, 5 ; move CF into bit #5 (use CL register for dynamic)
or al, dl ; merge into al
```

Comment: I do not understand. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

"...*but I do not know how to set the bit in position*..."

Understandable. There are a zillion instructions.

The first one, `SHR` (and `SHL`, ignored for this discussion) which you have chosen to use, will fiddle the carry flag to contain the bit on the edge (of the source register) that you shifted out.

There is another instruction, `RCL` (and `RCR`, similarly ignored for this discussion) which will put the carry bit into the bit on the other edge (of the target register) which you will "shift in" so to speak

Do this eight times in a row and you'll have your "reverse-o-matic" procedure done.

Here are two pages that describe these two instructions, including a little picture...

[Penguin Explains SHR instruction](http://www.penguin.cz/~literakl/intel/s.html#SHR)

[Penguin Explains RCL instruction](http://www.penguin.cz/~literakl/intel/r.html#RCL)

Hey, this is easy, so, free code, just because I feel nice today...

```
    Mov     AL,Some_Number          ;Define this somewhere
    Sub     AH,AH                   ;Not really needed, placed here to help newcomers understand

    SHR     AL,1                    ;Get the bottom bit (bit #0) from AL
    RCL     AH,1                    ;Put it into the top bit of AH

    SHR     AL,1                    ;Now get bit #1
    RCL     AH,1                    ;Put it into the top bit of AH

    SHR     AL,1                    ;Now get bit #2
    RCL     AH,1                    ;Put it into the top bit of AH

    SHR     AL,1                    ;Now get bit #3
    RCL     AH,1                    ;Put it into the top bit of AH

    SHR     AL,1                    ;Now get bit #4
    RCL     AH,1                    ;Put it into the top bit of AH

    SHR     AL,1                    ;Now get bit #5
    RCL     AH,1                    ;Put it into the top bit of AH

    SHR     AL,1                    ;Now get bit #6
    RCL     AH,1                    ;Put it into the top bit of AH

    SHR     AL,1                    ;Now get bit #7
    RCL     AH,1                    ;Put it into the top bit of AH

    Mov     Reverse_Pattern,AH      ;The pattern is now exactly backwards
```

Tested it and let us know if this works

Comment: I did not know about the existence of RCL. Thank you.